# Error while change of text inside a label

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When i try to change the text inside a label I got an error saying like 
`Unexpected call to method or property access.`

used code:

```
$("#lableText").text('12')
```

or

```
$("#lableText").text(numberOfPages)
```

Can any one please assist me on this?

Comment: same error even `$("#textLable").html('hi')`

Comment: you sure #textLable is not #textLabel?

Comment: Are other jquery calls working?

Comment: lableText is lable tag. <lable id="lableText"/> ?

Comment: It's important to confirm that you are spelling `label` correctly.

Comment: Using a 'wrong' identifier, does not result in the `Unexpected call to method or property access.` error, it will simply just do nothing. I really think it's because $ is hijacked by another lib as I answered.

Comment: @ Brendan, Thank you. i have wrongly spelled.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine, maybe $ is hijacked by another library maybe? What does `jQuery("#lableText").text('12')` do?